# How to use scrollview for showing third cards after scrolling?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have three cards. I want to show two cards at one time and user can see third card when user scroll it down. But right now it is showing three cards at one time by decreasing the height of each card. I want three cards of same height.

This is my layout xml file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.coderz.creative.music.Fragment.HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/chart_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/pie_chart_spend"
                >
            </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/bar_chart_spend"
                >
            </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/pie_chart_spend_on_click"
                >
            </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You want to show two cards (filling up the whole screen) and a third card below them, all having the same height?

Comment: yeah elmorabea. I want this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **ScrollView** like below. I've set the height of the cards to 250dp, but you can adjust it to your needs. Keep in mind that it will look differently on different screen sizes, since the height is fixed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.coderz.creative.music.Fragment.HomeFragment">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chart_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                    android:id="@+id/pie_chart_spend"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                    android:id="@+id/bar_chart_spend"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                    android:id="@+id/pie_chart_spend_on_click"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Ok colens. Thanks for your answer. It is working as I want. But is fixing the height better approach? Is there any other better approach other than fix the height?

Comment: Yes, divide the height of the parent by 2, and dynamically assign the height to your cards